# Massive SQL row insert

Tags: php, mysqli

I have to load some location strings in an SQL database, but there are too many to insert every single row manually. So I wanted to set all the strings in a single textarea, and once the form is submitted serialize all the data. Something like this:

**TEXTAREA DATA**

```html
Buenos Aires
Catamarca
Chaco
Chubut
Capital Federal
Córdoba
Corrientes
Entre Rios
Formosa
Jujuy
La Pampa
La Rioja
Mendoza
Misiones
Neuquén
Río Negro
Salta
San Juan
San Luis
Santa Cruz
Santa Fe
Santiago Del Estero
Tierra Del Fuego
Tucumán
```

And once there identify every single string with PHP in order to then insert it in the database. How do I achieve this?

Comment: Is there anything on the ground yet? Any Code?

Comment: We can not write the code for you, sorry. Try something and then paste your code if you encounter any problem.

Comment: explode, foreach, insert

Comment: sorry. i was not clear enought. I am looking for a function to set every row of the textarea as a different variable

Comment: `to set every row of the textarea as a different variable` - Why would you want that? Better stick with the original goal ;-)

Answer (score 1):

You could use a [prepared statement](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php)* to reduce some of the load on the database server.

```
$stmt = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO yourtable (thefield) VALUE (?)');
$stmt->bindParam(1, $loc);

$locations = preg_split('![\r\n]+!', $theTextAreaValue, -1,  PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
foreach($locations as $loc)
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

also have a read of

- http://docs.php.net/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html
- https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-myisam-bulk-data-loading.html

---

edit: *) and you get protection against [sql injection's](http://php.net/security.database.sql-injection) for this kind of queries as well.

Comment: is `$stmt->bindParam(1, $loc);` not supposed to be within your loop?

Comment: No, it's not. You bind the parameter once and then you { change the parameter's value and execute the statement } within the loop.

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_POST['data'])){
  $lines  = explode("\n", $_POST['data']);
  $lines  = array_map('trim', $lines);
  $lines  = implode("'), ('", $lines);
  $query = "INSERT INTO table (field) VALUES ('".$lines."');";  
 }
```

Comment: Thanks! +1. The function I needed was explode!

Answer (score 0):

```
$from_textarea = $_POST['text_area_name_attribute'];
$array = explode("\n" , $from_textarea);

foreach($array as $k => $v) {
    mysql_query("insert into table_name(column_name) values('".trim($v)."') ");   
}
```

Comment: Thanks! +1. The function I needed was explode!